# Grouping nodes based on a rule set

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have:

```
<node handle="full"/>
<node handle="full"/>
<node handle="left"/>
<node handle="right"/>
<node handle="top-left"/>
<node handle="top-right"/>
<node handle="bottom"/>
<node handle="full"/>
<node handle="full"/>
```

I need to group these nodes based on the following logic:

- `full` should be on its own.
- `left` should group with a minimum of 1 and a maximum 2 extra nodes of type `right`, `top-right`, `bottom-right`.
- `right` should group with a minimum of 1 and a maximum 2 extra nodes of type `left`, `top-left`, `bottom-left`.
- `top-left` should group with a minimum of 2 and a maximum of 3 nodes of type `bottom-right`, `top-right`, `bottom-right`, `bottom`.
- …

Obviously if I start from `left` and the `following-sibling` is `right`, the process should reset and continue with the next element.

So the output should look like:

```
<group>
    <node handle="full"/>
</group>
<group>
    <node handle="full"/>
</group>
<group>
    <node handle="left"/>
    <node handle="right"/>
</group>
<group>
    <node handle="top-left"/>
    <node handle="top-right"/>
    <node handle="bottom"/>
</group>
<group>
    <node handle="full"/>
</group>
<group>
    <node handle="full"/>
</group>
```

Is there an efficient (for both humans and machines) way to handle this or should it be managed case-by-case in code?

---

### EDIT 1:

I *think* I could define my rule-set like this, and then compare against it on a case-by-case:

```
<xsl:variable name="layouts">
    <opt start="left" min="1" max="2">
        <allow pos="right"          value="2"/>
        <allow pos="top-right"      value="1"/>
        <allow pos="bottom-right"   value="1"/>
    </opt>
    <opt start="right" min="1" max="2">
        <allow pos="left"           value="2"/>
        <allow pos="top-left"       value="1"/>
        <allow pos="bottom-left"    value="1"/>
    </opt>
</xsl:variable>
```

I would be using a `max` score from which I would subtract the `value` of each element added.
How's that look?

---

### EDIT 2:

The solution I've found to work moments before **Tim C** posted his answer.
The first difference I see between the two is that my version limits the acceptable start elements for a sequence (left, top-left). I don't know anymore if this is a good thing or a limitation I introduced to avoid matching nodes which are already made part of a sequence.
Whichever the case, Tim's aswer is *way* more elegant than mine.

```
<!-- 
    For each /item:

    - see it it's one of the starting points of a sequence:
        - Not "full"
        - Left, Top-Left

    - if full, just return the element
    - if not full and not a starting point, skip it, since it means it being added by the previous item.
    - if not full and either of the starting points, kick into a recursion loop in a separate template:

    - store the item's current "score" (2 or 1 for single-quadrant images)
    - recur through the following-siblings with a counter for position(), checking if they are in the allowed list, and decreasing the "score" counter.
    - every time a match is found:
        - recreate the "allow" list, minus the current match, and pass the updated list to the next iteration
        - decrease the counter
    - if the iteration completes, reaching zero, return the position() of the last matched item
    - if during the iteration, while the score is still >0, a match is not found, return false(). Our sequence is broken, we have a user error.

    - the calling template (the one matching *every* item) checks whether the returned result is >0 or false()
    - if >0 returns a copy of every node up the number specified by >0
    - if false() print out and error, suggesting possible sequences.
-->

<xsl:variable name="layouts">
    <start handle="left"            score="2">      <!-- The starting score which we'll subtract from on every iteration -->
        <allow handle="right"           value="2"/> <!-- the acceptable position which we'll check against on every iteration -->
        <allow handle="top-right"       value="1"/> <!-- the value for each position which we'll subtract from the <start> score -->
        <allow handle="bottom-right"    value="1"/>
    </start>
    <start handle="top-left"        score="3">
        <allow handle="right"           value="2"/>
        <allow handle="bottom-left"     value="1"/>
        <allow handle="top-right"       value="1"/>
        <allow handle="bottom-right"    value="1"/>
    </start>
    <start handle="full"            score="0"/> <!-- Position which are not acceptable as the start of a sequence are scored 0 -->
    <start handle="right"           score="0"/>
    <start handle="top-right"       score="0"/>
    <start handle="bottom-right"    score="0"/>
    <start handle="bottom-left"     score="0"/>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- Applied to every /item -->
<xsl:template mode="imagewraps" match="item">
    <xsl:param name="i" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="nodeName"   select="name(.)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="layout"     select="exsl:node-set($layouts)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="position"   select="position/item/@handle"/>
    <xsl:variable name="score"      select="$layout/start[@handle = $position]/@score"/>
    <xsl:variable name="allowList"  select="$layout/start[@handle = $position]"/>

    <!-- This variable will store the final result of the recursion lanunched from within.
         The returned value will be a number, indication the position of the last node that is part of the sequence -->
    <xsl:variable name="sequenceFound">
        <xsl:if test="$score > 0">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="test" select="parent::node()/*[name() = $nodeName][$i +1]">
                <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i +1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="score"        select="$score"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="allowList"    select="$allowList"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>


    <div style="border: 1px solid red">
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- If the $score is 0 and the position is 'full' just return a copy if the current node -->
        <xsl:when test="$score = 0 and $position = 'full'">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- if the $score is greater than 0, return a copy of the current node
             and the siblings the follow, up to the value stored in $sequenceFound -->
        <xsl:when test="$score > 0">
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- Actually do the above only if $sequenceFound didn't end up being 0
                     (it currently never does, but good to have as an option to handle errors in here) -->
                <xsl:when test="$sequenceFound != 0">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::*[$sequenceFound - $i >= position()]"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <!-- If the first item is wrong, let jsut say it -->
        <xsl:when test="$score = 0 and position() > 1">
            <xsl:message>The first item should either be "full", "left", "top-left".</xsl:message>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="test" match="*">
    <xsl:param name="i"/>
    <xsl:param name="score"/>
    <xsl:param name="allowList"/>
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="nodeName"       select="name()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="position"       select="position/item/@handle"/>
    <xsl:variable name="isInAllowList"  select="count($allowList/allow[@handle = $position]) > 0"/>
    <xsl:variable name="value">
        <xsl:if test="$isInAllowList">
            <xsl:value-of select="$allowList/allow[@handle = $position]/@value"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="allowListMinusMatched">
        <xsl:if test="$isInAllowList">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$allowList/allow[@handle != $position]"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$isInAllowList">
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- if we've not ran out of loops, continue -->
                <xsl:when test="($score - $value) > 0">
                    <xsl:apply-templates mode="test" select="parent::node()/*[name() = $nodeName][$i +1]">
                        <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i +1"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="allowList" select="$allowListMinusMatched"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="score" select="$score - $value"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="($score - $value) = 0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$i"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="layout"     select="exsl:node-set($layouts)"/>
            <xsl:variable name="allowed"  select="$layout/start[@handle = $position]"/>
            <xsl:message>Bombing out. Wrong Sequence.</xsl:message>
            <xsl:message>
                Items allowed after "<xsl:value-of select="$allowed/@handle"/>" are:
                <xsl:for-each select="$allowed/allow">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@handle"/>
                    <xsl:if test="count($allowed/allow) > position()">, </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="count($allowed/allow) = position()">.</xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:message>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed a solution for this, but I wasn't entirely sure about the 'minimum' requirement. However, I will post what I have done so far, should it help....

Firstly, I defined an **xsl:key** for each of the rules. For example, for the **left** rule:

```
<xsl:key name="left" 
 match="node[@handle='right' or @handle='top-right' or @handle='bottom-right']" 
 use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::node[@handle='left'][1])"/>
```

So, in this case, it matches **right**, **top-right** and **bottom-right** elements, and links them to most preceding **left** element. Note this will pick up more elements that you need, should there be a **bottom** element between the **left** and **right** element. This will be handled a bit later...

Then, I created a template for matching the first **node** in the group. Initially, I defined a variable to contain the following nodes using the relevant **xsl:key** (where **$maximum** is a variable containing the maximum number of nodes)

```
<xsl:variable name="followingNodes" 
 select="key(@handle, generate-id())[position() &lt;= $maximum]" />
```

However, this will pick up elements where there may be a invalid element in between. To stop this, I first calculated the position of the current node...

```
<xsl:variable name="position" select="count(preceding-sibling::node)"/>
```

Then I could check whether the position of the node in the key equals the position relative to the current node, in which case there are no invalid elements before them.

```
<xsl:variable 
 name="followingNodes" 
 select="key(@handle, generate-id())[position() &lt;= $maximum][count(preceding-sibling::node) - $position &lt;= position()]"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="left" 
      match="node[@handle='right' or @handle='top-right' or @handle='bottom-right']" 
      use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::node[@handle='left'][1])"/>

   <xsl:key name="right" 
      match="node[@handle='left' or @handle='top-left' or @handle='bottom-left']" 
      use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::node[@handle='right'][1])"/>

   <xsl:key name="top-left" 
      match="node[@handle='bottom-right' or @handle='top-right' or @handle='bottom-right' or @handle='bottom']" 
      use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::node[@handle='top-left'][1])"/>

   <xsl:template match="nodes">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node[1]" mode="first"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="node[@handle='full']" mode="first">
      <group>
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </group>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node[1]" mode="first"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="node" mode="first">
      <xsl:variable name="maximum">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@handle='top-left'">3</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>2</xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="position" select="count(preceding-sibling::node)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="followingNodes" select="key(@handle, generate-id())[position() &lt;= $maximum][count(preceding-sibling::node) - $position &lt;= position()]"/>
      <group>
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="$followingNodes"/>
      </group>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node[count($followingNodes) + 1]" mode="first"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to the following input XML...

```
<nodes>
    <node handle="full"/>
    <node handle="full"/>
    <node handle="left"/>
    <node handle="right"/>
    <node handle="top-left"/>
    <node handle="top-right"/>
    <node handle="bottom"/>
    <node handle="full"/>
    <node handle="full"/>
</nodes>
```

The output is as follows:

```
<group>
   <node handle="full"/>
</group>
<group>
   <node handle="full"/>
</group>
<group>
   <node handle="left"/>
   <node handle="right"/>
</group>
<group>
   <node handle="top-left"/>
   <node handle="top-right"/>
   <node handle="bottom"/>
</group>
<group>
   <node handle="full"/>
</group>
<group>
   <node handle="full"/>
</group>
```

Comment: That looks really smart! I found a different solution, which looks less lean and doesn't use keys. I'm appending it to my own question. I'd be curious to know what you think of it.

Comment: The "min" requirement is useless. I thought I needed it to set a range to the recursion. But obviously we both made it without it.